# highlighting and un highlighting the button

Tags: c#, button, highlight

What I want to do is when a user clicked on the button("Add to Cart"), it will then change its color and change to ("added to cart") which I managed to do.

My query is when the user clicked again the "added to cart" button, the highlight turns off and goes back to ("add to cart") . Everything works fine, however, when I try to remove all of the product from the highlight, one product stays highlighted. for example i have 4 products added and when i decide to remove them from being added, one product stays highlighted and has the "added to cart" text.

here is the code for the button click:

```
protected void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ProductID = Convert.ToInt16((((Button)sender).CommandArgument)).ToString();
        string ProductQuantity = "1";

        DataListItem currentItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem;
        Label lblAvailableStock = currentItem.FindControl("lblAvailableStock") as Label;

        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
            var checkProduct = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ProductID") == ProductID); // check whether product is already added or not
            if (checkProduct.Count() == 0)
            {
                string query = "select * from Products where ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
                DataTable dtProducts = GetData(query);

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
                dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
                dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
                dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
                dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
                dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
                dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                Session["MyCart"] = dt;
                btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (checkProduct.Count() != 0)
                {
                    var ProductRowToBeDeleted = dt.Select("ProductID =" + ProductID);
                    foreach (var row in ProductRowToBeDeleted)
                    {
                        row.Delete();
                        btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string query = "select * from Products where ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
            DataTable dtProducts = GetData(query);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //storing all of the records

            dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string)); // adding the columns
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ImageUrl", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductQuantity", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AvailableStock", typeof(string));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); //adding the rows
            dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
            dr["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Name"]);
            dr["Description"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Description"]);
            dr["Price"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["Price"]);
            dr["ImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProducts.Rows[0]["ImageUrl"]);
            dr["ProductQuantity"] = ProductQuantity;
            dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock.Text;  

            dt.Rows.Add(dr); //adding the data row in the data table. 

            Session["MyCart"] = dt; //asigning the datatable in the session.
            btnIslandGas.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
        HighLightCartProducts();
    }
```

and this is the code for the highlight products (working fine)

```
private void HighLightCartProducts()
    {
        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtProductsAddedToCart = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
            if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataListItem item in dlProducts.Items)
                {
                    HiddenField hfProductID = item.FindControl("hfProductID") as HiddenField; // Getting hidden filed value
                    if (dtProductsAddedToCart.AsEnumerable().Any(row => hfProductID.Value == row.Field<String>("ProductID")))
                    {
                        //item.BackColor =  System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                        Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button; //item.FinControl finds the item(Button)
                        btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                        btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        btnAddToCart.Text = "Added to Cart";

                        Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
                        imgGreenstar.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button;
                        btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                        btnAddToCart.Text = "Add to Cart";
                        Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
                        imgGreenstar.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the unhighlight method:

```
 private void RemoveHighLightCartProducts(string ProductId)
    {

        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtProductsAddedToCart = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];
            //delete row which contains product data.

            var ProductRowToBeDeleted = dtProductsAddedToCart.Select("ProductID =" + ProductId);
            foreach (var row in ProductRowToBeDeleted)
            {
                row.Delete();
            }
            foreach (DataListItem item in dlProducts.Items)
            {


                Button btnAddToCart = item.FindControl("btnAddToCart") as Button;
                btnAddToCart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                btnAddToCart.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                btnAddToCart.Text = "Add to Cart";
                Image imgGreenstar = item.FindControl("imgStar") as Image;
                imgGreenstar.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

please help me out, i really need to make this work. thank you for acknowledging.

Comment: " when I try to remove all of the product from the highlight" what are you doing in this step

Comment: im clicking on the btn addtocart. @MicrosoftDN

Comment: what i want to do is like the like and unlik button on facebok. when you 1st click it, it will be highlighted and change the text to added to cart. the 2nd time you click it, it will go back to original color and text (add to cart) @MicrosoftDN

Comment: really cant figure out what im missing here. theres always that one product that is highlighted but is removed yet it is highlighted. pls help me @MicrosoftDN

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for ask here, but where are you apllying RemoveHighLightCartProducts? did you tried before ou after row removed from cart?

Comment: removehighlight method lets user to unhighlight the product they dont want anymore.

Comment: yes, but where are you calling it? i see how the code works, but i can not find where is it being called. every time you remove a row, you should call the removehigjlight method with the product id, for example :

var ProductRowToBeDeleted = dt.Select("ProductID =" + ProductID);

**removehighlight(ProductID);**

foreach (var row in ProductRowToBeDeleted)

Comment: im confused. im doing this for a while now.

Comment: i edited my coment, after you check if the product, in the first if -> first else -> inside the if , put the **RemoveHighLightCartProducts(ProductID);** and check if this works out. is right after row.delete()

Comment: nothing happened sir. i inserted RemoveHighLightCartProducts(ProductId); after the row.delete()

Comment: try to debug and set 2 stops, one after you added the 4 items, and another after you removed them to check the values in both on them. if after you created it only has 3 items, not the four of them its because one of them is being loss. i'm trying to see where's the problem but at this moment, this is the only place where it makes sense to be

Comment: really confused on what am i missing in the code. :(

Comment: still cant figure this one out :(

Comment: Last try i hope: did you try to change the `if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count > 0)` to `if (dtProductsAddedToCart.Rows.Count >= 0)`

Comment: woah @Alexer99, youre the best :)

Comment: Sorry for take this long, what was happening it was in the table, the positions on table start at 0, and you where starting counting them ate position 1. also, i think that you dont need the removehighlighted function, you already do it in the highlight.

Comment: thanks again! youre a legend! :) i have another query if thats okay?

Comment: given that already i have 3 products chosen(they are highlighted) then i clicked on the checkout button. then i go back to the choose product page. what happened is that the 3 products that are highlighted is not highlighted anymore. in short it has refreshed. any idea?

Comment: Ok, if they're already checked on **Session["MyCart"]**, is just run the HighLightCartProducts() when you open the page. This will compare your products with products that are in MyCart and select them.